# Probability of fires hitting the target.

Tags: probability

**Question**
A machine fires its first shot and hits the target, but it misses its second shot. All its
subsequent shots have a probability of hitting the target equal to the proportion of
targets hit beforehand. For example, if it hits 5 out of the first 8 shots, then the 9th shot
has a probability of 5/8  to hit the target. If the probability that it hits exactly 50 out of its
first 100 shots expressed as a/b where a and b are coprime positive integers, what is the
value of a + b?

I dont understand how to progress for this question . Can somebody give me a hint for solve this question .

Comment: What have you tried?  Small numbers of balls might give you a clue

Comment: Where does the question comes from? If it comes from a contest, please edit your post to mention it.

Comment: Hint: Henry’s hint is excellent. And the result is surprising.

Comment: You may try finding the pmf of $$S_n=X_1+\dots +X_n$$ where $X_j=1$ iff the target is hit on the $j^{\text{th}}$ attempt.